# SDL_net how to get the UDP remote address?

Tags: c++, networking, sockets

I have a problem with the tcp and udp synchronization.

On the server it accepted the tcp connection with the: `SDLNet_TCP_Accept();`
But now I need to know how to get the remote address of the udp_socket of the client to use it to send upd packets.

I already tried to use(on the server) the function `SDLNet_TCP_GetPeerAddress();` to get it. The ip was right, but the port was't. I tried the `SDLNet_UDP_GetPeerAddress();` (on the client) but it just gives the local address.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TCP connection "doesn't know" anything about any UDP connections. If you established TCP connection and want to send additional UDP packets, you will have to determine the the correct port yourself.

You can have the client send the port number via your existing TCP connection. This won't work if client is behind NAT though.

The best solution would be to have the client initiate both TCP and UDP connections. Or, try limiting your communication to just UDP or just TCP.